# How to Disable HTTP protocol for OPTIONS Verb?

Tags: api, iis, https, security-testing

In our application(Deployed in IIS), we have enabled only HTTPS(Disabled HTTP access).

[image]

While accessing API endpoint using http protocol with OPTIONS verb, its returning 200 Ok response.
[image]
How to fix?

Comment: You can easily use URL Rewrite rule to block such requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the `OPTIONS verb` in IIS, the steps are as follows:

Start the IIS Manager, double-click to open the `Request Filtering module`, select `HTTP Verbs`, select `Deny Verb…` on the right, enter `OPTIONS` and click OK.

[Disable OPTIONS Verb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1fZU.png)